# Problem about output Q does not correct logic of jk flip-flop but it's look like logic of nand gate

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, flipflop, pspice

I'm try to simulation  jk flip-flop on Pspice follow pic.

[image]

Use tsmc180nm model to nmos and pmos

```
W = 4um for M1,M2,M10,M11,M4,M5,M6,M3
W = 3um for M7,M8,M9,M14,M15,M16
W = 1um fot M12,M13
L = 180nm for all mosfet
```

Next this is signal from input that j=k for togle output ,clk and output Q

[image]

Problem is output Q does not correct logic of jk flip-flop but it's look like logic of nand gate

Why my jk flip-flop work wrong logic?

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you've drawn is complicated, but we can prove that it doesn't operate as a flip-flop by analyzing a small part of it.

Let's look at the pull-down chain on Q, formed by (M7-M8-M9)||(M12).

If CLK and K are high, then M7 and M8 are on, shorting Q to the drain of M9. It's clear that Q cannot be high because if it were high, then M9 would be turned on as well, and Q would be shorted to ground.

If Q cannot be high when CLK and K are both high, then this circuit cannot be any type of flip-flop, and in fact, as you mentioned, it operates more like NAND(CLK,K).

We could continue to analyze the rest of this transistor circuit and determine what changes would be needed to make it operate like a JK flip-flop. However, you could also make your life a lot simpler by thinking at the gate level.

A JK flip-flop can be constructed from two 3-input NANDs and two 2-input NANDs as shown in [this reference](https://circuitglobe.com/jk-flip-flop.html).

If you want to implement a JK flop at the transistor level, simply implement a three-input NAND and a two-input NAND with transistors, then connect them together as shown.